# Convert HTML (tinyMCE) to WORD (.docx)

Tags: php, html, ms-word, tinymce

I've been successfully able to generate a `.docx` document with https://github.com/djpate/docxgen but as soon as i try to include TinyMCE text, i no longer can open the document. (non valid char).

Is there a way to convert the HTML text before giving it to docxgen to avoid such error?

Comment: Have you tried anything like the following : html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");  Are you saving to file at anypoint?  Can you show the illegal character?  Is it part of a BOM i.e. ï»¿

Comment: http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've decided to go with the pro version of the library http://www.phpdocx.com/ as it simplifies the whole process. I hope it'll fill my needs.

Comment: This software is privative and you have to pay to use almost every useful function, so it isn't a good solution.

Comment: It's better than nothing. If you have a better solution, feel free to add it.

Comment: Did phpdocx.com fill your needs Tristan?
I too am thinking about buying this (embedHTML() is in the pro version)

Comment: Yeah but I must warn you that the library is way beyond good coding standard but it does what we need.

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I settled with this answer to create a doc (simply output html and Word will recognize it):

```
    header( 'Content-Type: application/msword' ); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" .date("Y-m-d").".doc");  
    /*
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" .date("Y-m-d").".rtf");
    */
    $html = preg_replace('%/[^\\s]+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)%i', 'http://www.akubocrm.com\\0', $html);

    print "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\"";
    print "xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"";
    print "xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\"";
    print "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">";
    print "<xml>
     <w:WordDocument>
      <w:View>Print</w:View>
      <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
      <w:PunctuationKerning/>
      <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
      <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
     </w:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    ";

    die($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/ which just recently came out.

I, however, tried it and it messed up my invoice (granted I used tables where I shouldn't have)

Jim